# Required Field Validator in Gridview depend on condition c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a required field validator in a Gridview. I want fire the validater only if the ddlPartsStatus is "Ordered". I just can't get it to work.

At the moment required field validator fires for all the textboxes.

my code

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPartsToOrderDetail" CssClass="gvPartsToOrderDetail" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvPartsToOrderDetail_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ticket Number">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTicketNo" Text='<%# Eval("TicketNo") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTxtTicketNo" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Medium" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtTicketNo" ValidationGroup="Submit"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Parts Status">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPartStatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="-Select-"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Ordered"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" CssClass="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, they all fire together because they are all part of the same validation group with a single submit button.  The `ValidationGroup` property isn't "row mangled" on render to be unique to each row, though you can do it programatically in `RowDataBound`

Comment: @fnostro Is it possible to have a code snippet?

Comment: snippet overkill shown below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you need a `CustomValidator`. Then the `ClientValidationFunction` should evaluate both the TextBox and the DropDownList.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" 
    ValidationGroup="Submit" ControlToValidate="txtTicketNo" 
    ClientValidationFunction="checkValuesInRow" ValidateEmptyText="true"></asp:CustomValidator>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkValuesInRow(sender, element) {
        var isValid = false;
        var ddlValue = $("#" + sender.controltovalidate).closest('tr').find('select').val();
        if (element.Value === "" && ddlValue === "0") {
            isValid = true;
        }
        element.IsValid = isValid;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Pretty much what I was just writing, this is the correct answer.

Comment: @VDWWD If I enter something in the txtTicketNo the validator does not dissappear

Comment: You may need to tweak it a little to fit your correct ddl values. And if you have more than one ddl in the row, you better access it by class name for example.

Answer (score 1):

> NOTE: Further reading is intended to be informative and not practical given all the clicking that must happen.  But it shows how things *can* be done, not necessarily how the *should* be done and is only here due to the OP's Request for more info...so, here we go

Given this GridView `<ItemTemplate>`:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbxTicketNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TicketNo") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTxtTicketNo" runat="server" 
        ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" Text="*"
        ControlToValidate="tbxTicketNo"
        InitialValue="0"
        ValidationGroup="vgSubmit">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Renders a table with *x* number of validators based on your row count. You can use your browser's Developers Tools to inspect `gvPartsToOrderDetail` where you will find something similar to this, note the `data-val-validationgroup` attributes on all rows:

```
    <span 
      data-val-controltovalidate="ContentPlaceHolder1_gvPartsToOrderDetail_tbxTicketNo_0" 
      data-val-errormessage="RequiredFieldValidator" 
      data-val-validationgroup="vgSubmit"
      id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gvPartsToOrderDetail_rfvTxtTicketNo_0" 
      data-val="true" 
      data-val-evaluationfunction="RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid" 
      data-val-initialvalue="0" style="visibility:hidden;">*</span>
```

Do you see that `data-val-validationgroup="vgSubmit"` is not unique?
So when you click `btnSubmit` with its `ValidationGroup` set to "vgSubmit", they all get triggered.

Now given @VDWWD's answer you may well prefer to keep it this way. And that's perfectly fine and legal and likely more in line with your needs.

But to address the non-uniqueness of the Validation Group you can do this in the markup instead:

```
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTxtTicketNo" runat="server" 
        ...
        ValidationGroup='<%# string.Format("Submit_{0}", Container.DataItemIndex) %>'>
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

which will then render:

```
<span ... data-val-validationgroup="Submit_0" ... </span>
<span ... data-val-validationgroup="Submit_1" ... </span>
<span ... data-val-validationgroup="Submit_2" ... </span>
```

But now you have design problem.  To isolate the validation group in the gridview and to tie it to your submit button you need to select a row, which means introducing a Select command button.  More clicks, not good, but it can be done. But this introduces a couple of more issues:

```
1. How do you tell the Submit button which validation group to validate?
2. Also the Submit button has a nasty habit of Posting back regardless of validation.
```

Both can be fixed like this:

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Button" 
        OnClientClick="return Page_ClientValidate('vgSubmit_1')" />
```

which is generated programmatically in `btnSubmit_PreRender` as follows:

```
    protected void btnSubmit_PreRender( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        btnSubmit.OnClientClick = string.Format( "return Page_ClientValidate('vgSubmit_{0}')", gvPartsToOrderDetail.SelectedIndex );
    }
```

What follows is the Code behind and the page markup for review:

> To sum up, this solution, if you can call it that:
>
> 1. Unique validation group names PER ROW
> 2. Requires the addition of a selected row
> 3. Rendering the Submit button to prevent postbacks and isolate the appropriate validation group

I can only hope this was at least informative and maybe gave you some ideas about the versatility of Server controls.

Happy Programming...

Code behind:

```
namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            if ( !Page.IsPostBack )
            {
                List<Parts> ListOfParts = new List<Parts>( new Parts[ ] {
                            new Parts(0, 0),
                            new Parts(0, 0),            
                            new Parts(0, 0) } );

                gvPartsToOrderDetail.DataSource = ListOfParts;
                gvPartsToOrderDetail.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_PreRender( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            Button1.OnClientClick = string.Format( "return Page_ClientValidate('vgSubmit_{0}')", gvPartsToOrderDetail.SelectedIndex );
        }
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------
    // Dummy data class
    //
    public class Parts {
        public Parts( int ticketNo, int status ) {
            TicketNo = ticketNo;
            Status = status;
        }

        public int TicketNo { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the Markup:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3._Default" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvPartsToOrderDetail" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" ClientIDMode="Predictable">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Ticket">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="tbxTicketNo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TicketNo") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTxtTicketNo" runat="server" 
                        ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" Text="*"
                        ControlToValidate="tbxTicketNo"
                        ValidationGroup='<%# string.Format("vgSubmit_{0}", Container.DataItemIndex) %>'>
                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Parts Status">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPartStatus" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="[ Select ]" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Ordered" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Button" 
        OnClientClick='See code in PreRender' 
        OnPreRender="btnSubmit_PreRender" />

</asp:Content>
```